# How to get a shell script to open up a python gui on startup

Tags: command-line, system, autostart

I have a project with a couple Raspberry Pi's. I have created a monitor of sorts that needs to run so long as the pi has power. I Name my program

```
"prodmain.py"
```

But I launch it through an update script called

```
"refresh.sh"
```

The code in that looks like

```
xhost +
cd /home/pi/src/ProductionMonitor
git pull
cp /home/pi/src/ProductionMonitor/* /home/pi/Desktop/Production
cd /home/pi/Desktop/Production
cp /home/pi/Desktop/Production/refreshCode.sh /home/pi/Desktop/
/usr/bin/python3 prodmain.py 2>&1 >> logfile.data
```

This pulls my updated code and executes it using python3. the shell script works fine. but when I attempt to put this into any sort of auto start up mechanism it doesn't work.

Im trying to test this in a Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual box. It never comes up. If I look at the system log my best guess is an email that says

```
no protocol specified
xhost: unable to open display ":0"
```

With some research I think that this may be a problem with the display manager not working at the time the script is run but I'm not sure.

What is any modern way of doing this. I have found lots of answers for old systems. I have tried Chron, SystemD, Putting the Shell file in the autostart folder. I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Try putting `sleep 15` at top of script. No idea if it will work but it might.

Comment: Pretty Simple on the pi. I just added a line to /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart  @/home/pi/Desktop/refreshCode.sh. I guess Ill just abandon the test environment auto start which is fine

Comment: Can you post an answer and accept it?

Comment: I only have a working answer for the pi. for the testing environment I still have no success